# JsPdf ficando com conteúdo enorme

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf

Esotu utilizando a bilbioteca JsPdf em uma aplicação Angular. Porem, quando salvo o pdf, ele fica gigantesco (imagem anexo).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrDSG.png)

Estou utilizando widths de 100% no html (ja tentei tb com 21cm por ser largura de uma pagina a4)
A criação do documento está da seguinte forma

```
 const doc = new jsPDF('p','cm','a4')
  
     doc.html(this.htmlData.nativeElement,{width:21,windowWidth:21,margin:0,x:0,y:0,autoPaging:true,
      callback:(pdf)=>{
        
        pdf.save("teste.pdf")
      }
     })
```

Já tentei converter todas as medidas para cm no css também, porém sem sucesso.
Já tentei não utilizar flexbox (ou até inserir o -webkit) também sem sucesso.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ola,

Eu consegui ajustando as configurações, estou usando num projeto Svelte.

Vou compartilhar meu código, acredite te ajudar com relação ao tamanho do conteúdo a ser gerado no PDF...

```js
function generationPdf() {
    const pdf = new jsPDF({
      format: 'a4',
      orientation: "portrait",
      unit: "mm",
    });
    
    const element = document.body
    showButton = false;

    
    pdf.html(element, {
      callback: function (pdf) {
        pdf.save("output.pdf");
      },
      width: 210, //define o tamanho do pdf - a4
      windowWidth: 1080 
    });
  }
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tb estou usando as configurações e nao resolveu. mudei a lib. estou usando a DynamicPdf. Resolveu e ficou otimo